# Add custom iptables rule to UFW to be persistent

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I would like to add the following rule to block the access for a specific user in Ubuntu 22.04 and persist whenever UFW is on. Is there a mechanism to do this while playing nicely with the UFW?

```
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 130 -j DROP
```

I tried adding this rule to the "/etc/ufw/before.rules" file already, but it seems like the rule is completely ignored.  Do I need to add the rule to a different chain maybe? Is there an entirely different mechanism for custom rules like this?

Comment: No. Packets don't have user identification.

Comment: No, you can't get it to work nicely inside of UFW or no this rule doesn't work because packets don't have user identification, because I have it working just fine when I type it from the CLI.. I am just working on making it come up automatically when ubuntu starts.